# Go with Generics: type parameter T is not comparable with ==

Tags: go, generics, comparable

I am playing around with Go Generics in the playground, trying to write some generic array functions.

https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/vS7f_Vxxy2j

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func array_has[T any](haystack []T, needle T) bool {
    for _, val := range haystack {
        if val == needle {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}


func main() {
    arr := []string{"A","B","C"}
    fmt.Println(array_has(arr, "T"))
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> invalid operation: val == needle (type parameter T is not comparable with ==)

I can work around it by using reflect:

`if reflect.ValueOf(val).Interface() == reflect.ValueOf(needle).Interface()`

Go2 Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/9ZVZafQ_9JK

However, is there an (internal?) interface for "comparable" types, for which `==` is defined, that I can use instead of `any`?

Are there really even types that do not support comparison with `==`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Comparison operators `==` and `!=` can be used only on parametrized types that  are indeed comparable. Referring to the [Go specs: Comparison Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable.

By using the type constraint `any`, you are allowing literally any type, including those that are not comparable (slices, maps and functions), thus producing the compiler error you saw.

Instead you can use the predeclared constraint `comparable` that restricts the type parameter to those that define `==` and `!=`, [except interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505556/is-there-a-go-generic-type-constraint-that-captures-the-ability-to-use-a-type-as/71508007#71508007).

So the correct way to write your function signature is

```
func array_has[T comparable](haystack []T, needle T) bool
```

Instead of `comparable` you can also use interface constraints that embed `comparable`, or stricter constraints that include only types that are comparable, e.g.:

```
func array_has[T ~string](haystack []T, needle T) bool
```

---

Note 1: types constrained by `comparable` allow `==` and `!=` but not order operators `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`. For details, see [In Go generics, why can't I use comparable constraint with order operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562572/in-go-generics-why-cant-i-use-comparable-constraint-with-order-operators/70562597#70562597)

---

Note 2: `comparable` is a [predeclared identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers), not a keyword. The difference is that you can redeclare it in a narrower scope and shadow the built-in one. To be clear [this program](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/qWXCAT3IVeL) compiles. This is good to know, as it's one of the reasons why the generics implementation is backwards compatible with earlier Go versions, i.e. old programs with variables named "comparable" will still compile.

---

The constraint `comparable` is also what you need to declare type parameters on **map keys**. Map keys must also support `==` and `!=` operators.

```
func useKeys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) {
    // use map keys
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As you can see from the [proposal, section "Operations permitted for any type"](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#operations-permitted-for-any-type), it is not directly possible to compare values of the `any` type. However, it's not the only possible generic constraint.

This is where [`comparable`](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#comparable-types-in-constraints) comes in, it allows using comparisons. You can replace the `any` with it and your function will work:

```
func array_has[T comparable](haystack []T, needle T) bool {
    for _, val := range haystack {
        if val == needle {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This works on the [playground](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/MDhZiYAnLe6).

I'm not sure if there are types that are *not* comparable using `==`, so that seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there really even types that do not support comparison with == ?

Yes, a lot. Maps and slices being a prominent example, functions an other.

When in doubt: Consult the spec.