# In Go generics, why can't I use comparable constraint with order operators?

Tags: go, generics

I am exploring go generics (1.18 beta), and have questions related to comparing two numerical values (a simple method that takes two values and returns a greater number).

For that, I am creating a custom numeric type that covers this type set (in the function `getBiggerNumber`):

```
int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | float32 | float64
```

However, added one more function but this time instead of using a custom type had used a `comparable` built-in constraint (in the function `getBiggerNumberWithComparable`).

But below code gives an error on this method as

> "invalid operation: cannot compare t1 > t2 (operator > not defined on T)"?

Any idea why the `>` operation did not work on built-in comparable types?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type numbers interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | float32 | float64
}

func getBiggerNumber[T numbers](t1, t2 T) T {
    if t1 > t2 {
        return t1
    }
    return t2
}

func getBiggerNumberWithComparable[T comparable](t1, t2 T) T {
    if t1 > t2 { // ./generics-sample.go:17:5: invalid operation: cannot compare t1 > t2 (operator > not defined on T)
        return t1
    }
    return t2
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getBiggerNumber(2.5, -4.0)) 
    fmt.Println(getBiggerNumberWithComparable(2.5, -4.0))
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`comparable` is the constraint for types that support equality operators `==` and `!=`. The language spec defines this in [Type constraints](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_constraints).

Notably, this includes anything that can be used as a map key, including arrays and structs with comparable fields. *(Types where the comparison may panic at run time, e.g. interfaces, [are excluded until Go 1.20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505556/is-there-a-go-generic-type-constraint-that-captures-the-ability-to-use-a-type-as/71508007#71508007))*.

It is true that in the Go language specifications, the [comparison operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) include order operators as (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`). This choice of terminology probably is what confuses you. However the specs also disambiguate:

> The equality operators `==` and `!=` apply to operands that are ***comparable***. The ordering operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` apply to operands that are ***ordered***.

#### Go 1.21

Use [`cmp.Ordered`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmp@master) from the standard library.

> The new cmp package defines the type constraint Ordered and two new generic functions Less and Compare that are useful with ordered types.

#### Go 1.18 to 1.20

In Go 1.18 the available constraint that supports the order operators such as `>` and `<` is [`constraints.Ordered`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Ordered)<sup>1</sup>:

```
type Ordered interface {
    Integer | Float | ~string
}
```

---

<sup>1: note that the package `golang.org/x/exp` is experimental. Its contents aren't guaranteed to be backwards compatible with new Go releases, but you can always copy-paste the definitions you need into your own code</sup>